# Existence of a power series converging non-uniformly to a continuous function

Tags: convergence-divergence, continuity, power-series

I am wondering whether there exist a function $f(z) = \sum_{n\geq0} a_n z^n$ such that:

- $f$ converges and is continuous on the closed unit disk $D$ and
- the series $\sum_n a_n z^n$ does not converge uniformly on $D$.

I have tried to construct a counter-example, but with no success so far.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/353760/462 (In the answer to the linked question, an $f$ is given that converges pointwise on the boundary of $D$, but its restriction to the boundary is discontinuous (so the convergence cannot be uniform).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  See D.R. Lick's article, ["Sets of non-uniform convergence of Taylor Series."](http://jlms.oxfordjournals.org/content/s1-39/1/81.extract)

It is shown there that for every closed subset $F$ of the boundary $\partial D$, there is such a series that converges everywhere on the closed disk to a continuous function, and whose set of non-uniform convergence is $F$.  This means that the series converges uniformly in a neighborhood (open arc) of each point in $\partial D\setminus F$, but not in any neighborhood of any point in $F$.

I have been interested in this question before, which is why I have a reference handy. I referred to this article in [another answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/257446/), to [a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/257224/) about power series in Banach algebras.  As mentioned there, the sequence of Cesàro means of the power series will converge uniformly on the closed disk.