# Analytic continuation on the unit disc

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an analytic function on the open unit disc $D=\{z \in \mathbb{C} \mid |z|<1\}$, suppose it is continuous on the the closure $\bar{D}$, then is $f$ also analytic on $\bar{D}$?

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/391707/46120) is a counter-example.

Comment: Great，thank you! I would like to consider it as an answer if you wrote in as an answer below.

Comment: You are welcome! Actually there are more pathological examples: $f$ could be not analytic at any point in $\partial D$. I hope you or someone else would provide an answer with more elaborate discussion.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/390407/462 provides a counterexample. If $f$ where analytic on $\bar D$, its series  would converge uniformly in a neighborhood of each point of $\partial D$ (and more). The given answer shows that we can have non-uniform convergence at every point of $\partial D$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple counterexample is $f(z)=\sqrt{1-z}$, where the square root is understood as the principal value. This function has a continuous extension to the closed disk, but it is not Lipschitz continuous on it. If it were holomorphic on a domain containing $\overline{D}$, it would be Lipschitz continuous on $\overline{D}$, due to the derivative being bounded.